# Internationalization Flutter "description" key in .arb files

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I'm having questions about internationalization in my Flutter App
I'm trying to get inspired from [I/O Pinball project from VGV](https://github.com/flutter/pinball)

In their l10n file they have a  `"description"` for each string, **is it for accessibility ?**

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "play": "Play",
  "@play": {
    "description": "Text displayed on the landing page play button"
  },
  "howToPlay": "How to Play",
  "@howToPlay": {
    "description": "Text displayed on the landing page how to play button"
  }
}
```

Does this "description" show up in voice over on iPhone ?
What should be the approach for writing such description ?

*-> Should it give details about the position of the string or label on the screen and so on... ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's metadata for the people who will be translating your strings - Including descriptions that give context to your localizable strings helps the translators produce more accurate translations.

Comment: I see thank you so much, but what if you'd like to use the same String at two entirely different locations and purpose in your app, how should that be expressed in the file ?

Comment: If they have different meanings, it's a good idea to create two separate localized strings. For example, if you have a string "Log" as in an entry in a logbook, and another string that says "Log" as in a piece of wood, you would want two different localizable strings to represent those, otherwise at least one of the translations will be inaccurate.

Comment: However, if it's the same word with the same meaning in different contexts, you don't necessarily have to include the context of where it's used in the app - Just enough context to ensure the correct meaning is conveyed.

Comment: I see thank you so much do you know if they are tools to auto-generate .arb files in other languages from for example one in english ?